# How can i design a database schema to handle employee scheduling?

Tags: sql, qt, schedule

I'm working on an employee scheduling client to help some folks create a schedule for their job. It should be able to count the hours each employee is scheduled and keep track of this.

The important part is this: I have one database table, employees, that stores employee information, such as employee id, name, and contact information. The difficult part is designing a table that stores the schedule itself. I thought about designing a table where each entry has an employee id, a date, and a shift time, but this seems incredibly inefficient.

What i am asking is this: How can i design the database and tables to allow for multiple employees per shift time, and multiple shifts per day? Also, how would i access this multiple table information from my code?

PERTINENT INFORMATION:
I am using c++ with Qt libraries.

It is in progress, so anything i have can be changed to allow for simpler database structures or access.

Comment: Are there standard shifts?  You could have a shift table:  shift(shiftID, shiftBegin, shiftEnd)  Then in your employee-shift table you would just have employeeID and shiftID.  Are you going to be tracking punch-in/punch-out time?  Or just the scheduled shifts?

Comment: That could work, but i'm unsure how to deal with everything being separated into 3 tables in the C++ code.

Comment: I don't have experience with that, I know there are database access libraries that allow for pretty straightforward sql querying in C++.  You'll probably get better results by changing the question to focus on the bit about querying SQL in C++. Then worry about ideal schema as a separate question.